# Google Map Information window

Tags: javascript, xml

I am using google map which shows marker with information window...in which i display address but i want to show the name as well in information window when a marker is clicked. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
  function load()
   {
   var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));  
       map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-37.816667,144.966667), 10); 
       map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
       map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

         var   geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
         GDownloadUrl("shops.xml", function(data) {

             var   xml = GXml.parse(data);
          shop = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("shop");
          for (var i = 0; i < shop.length; i++) {
          var name= shop[i].getElementsByTagName("name");
           name = name[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          var address= shop[i].getElementsByTagName("address");
            address = address[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            geocoder.getLocations(address, addToMap);}

              });  }

   function addToMap(response)
   {
      place = response.Placemark[0];
      point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],place.Point.coordinates[0]);

      function createMarker(point,address)
       {    
       var marker = new GMarker(point);    
       GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() 
       {    
        map.openInfoWindowHtml(point, address);    
       });    
       return marker; 
       } 
       map.addOverlay(createMarker(point, response.name)); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use API v3 and in your marker setup set the tite of the marker to "name" then after adding the click listener you will be able to refer to the title of the clicked marker - if that is what you wanted.

```
 //get your point and name whatever way you plan to do it
...

function createMarker(point,name){

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: point, 
  map: map,
  title: name,
}) ;

var content='Whatever info you want plus'+name;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});  
return marker; 
}
```

Please check the closures as I wrote it just now.
K